# How can I make Intellij wake my android from idle?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Whenever I build and run on my device, I have to turn on my device myself before the app is installed. I often forget to wake the android because building takes a long time. Other IDEs like Xcode wake the phone during a run by default. How can I make this change without having to keep my device constantly on?

Here's my run-configuration:
[image: run-configuration]

Comment: Set your device to leave the screen on while plugged in.

Comment: Can I make this change without having to keep my device constantly on?

Comment: @RosePerrone this is about the settings of your android device, nothing to do with what you have installed on your pc, there are settings to keep the phone awake while it's connected to the USB, search in your settings menu on your phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments indicate, this has little to do with your IDE and everything to do with your device.

On Android 4.x, you will find a "Stay awake" checkbox in Settings > Developer Options. Make sure that this checkbox is checked. That will keep the device awake while it is plugged in, so long as you do not manually press the power button. Note that on Android 4.2+, if you do not see Developer Options in Settings, go into the About page in Settings and tap on the build number seven times to unlock the hidden Developer Options.

On older devices, "Stay awake" will be elsewhere, usually in Settings > Applications, though it may vary by manufacturer.

Comment: meh I would hope there is a better way.  My battery lasts about 8-10 hours already and I couldn't imagine it lasting longer than an hour or two with the screen on.  Also, Eclipse can do this no problem so I am going to say it might be an IDE issue...

Comment: I agree that this is probably not the best answer, but you might want to note that it only proposes that the device would be kept awake *while plugged in*

Comment: @edthethird: "My battery lasts about 8-10 hours already and I couldn't imagine it lasting longer than an hour or two with the screen on" -- unless you have some device that doesn't charge by USB cable, this is not usually a problem. "Also, Eclipse can do this no problem" -- no, it does not. If the device is asleep, Eclipse does not wake up the screen, or get you past the keyguard.

Comment: Eh, forgetting about wireless ADB :P.   Also, Eclipse will block on a dialog waiting for an active USB device, while in Intellij it just fails the build immediately and I have to kick it off again (and wait around to be there to make sure my phone screen is on)